Measurability of the energy difference of two states with different mole numbers
In H.B. Callen's thermodynamics (2nd ed. p. 18), after expaining why "the methods of mechanics permit us to measure the energy difference of any two states with equal mole
numbers", the author continues to claim that:

The only remaining limitation to the measurability of the energy difference of any two states is the requirement that the states must have equal mole numbers. This restriction is easily eliminated by the following observation. Consider two simple subsystems separated by an impermeable wall and assume that the energy of each subsystem is known (relative to appropriate fiducial states, of course). If the impermeable wall is removed, the subsystems will intermix, but the total energy of the composite system will remain constant. Therefore the energy of the final mixed system is known to be the sum of the energies of the original subsystems. This technique enables us to relate the energies of states with different mole numbers.

I am kind of confused on the above explanation. For example, how to determine the energy difference of 1 mol $\mathrm{H}_2$ and 1 mol $\mathrm{He}$ with same volume via the above mentioned mechanical method?
Thanks very much for your attention!

Reference: Callen H.B - Thermodynamics And An Introduction To Thermostatistics-Wiley (1985), Section 1.7 in Page18

For 1mol of $H_2$ and 1 mol of $He$ one does not need the above method, since the mole numbers are the same, and we already know to measure the energy difference of any two states with equal mole numbers

Thanks for your answer. Here, although the mole number is equal, the species are differernt (H2 versus He). I suppose the claim "the methods of mechanics permit us to measure the energy difference of any two states with equal mole numbers" refers to equal mole numbers of all species.
